# How to abbreviated date in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, date

I want to covert a full date to a abbreviated form like for example :- **15 September 2020** to **15 SEP 20** in **javascript**
i have arrays of date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
const datum = '15 September 2020';

const words = datum.split(' ');

const str = `${words[0]} ${words[1].slice(0, 3).toUpperCase()} ${words[2].slice(2, 4)}`;
```